# How to post embed from non async method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to post a Embed when the Function "play_next()" is called. The Problem is that this Method is a non-asynchronize Method. Can someone explain to me how to make a async call from a non async method?

```
def play_next(self, ctx):
    self.voicechannel = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if len(self.song_queue) >= 1:
        del self.song_queue[0]
        source = os.path.join(self.QUEUE_PATH, self.song_queue[0])
        audio = MP3(source)
        await self.postEmbed(ctx, self.song_queue[0], audio.info.length)
        self.voicechannel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
    else:
        self.voicechannel.disconnect()
```

Edit:

```
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, url):
    connect_check = await self.join(ctx)
    if connect_check:
        video_title = self.getUrlTitle(url) + ".mp3"
        check_path = os.path.join(self.QUEUE_PATH, video_title)
        song = ""
        print(os.path.exists(check_path))
        if not os.path.exists(check_path):
            print("We are in IF")
            url_song = await self.download_song(url)
            song = os.path.join(self.QUEUE_PATH, url_song)
        else:
            print("We are in Else")
            song = check_path

        self.song_queue.append(song)
        if not self.voicechannel.is_playing():
            audio = MP3(song)
            await self.postEmbed(ctx, self.song_queue[0], audio.info.length)
            await self.voicechannel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=song), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
            self.voicechannel.volume = 100
            await ctx.send('Now playing...')
        else:
            await ctx.send('Song queued')
    else:
        await ctx.send("Der Bot ist bereits in einem Channel! Er kann nicht an zwei Orten gleichzeitig sein ;)")
```

Comment: Can you please update your question so it is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: so you want to call `play_next` from itself? Does this code need to be recursive?

Answer (score 0):

Using synchronous functions in discord bots, is a pretty bad idea, it could freeze the whole bot. In your case i would recommend just changing the `play_next` function to async.

Comment: But how could the call .play() then have to bee changed then?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this

```
async def play_next(self, ctx):
    voicechannel = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if len(self.song_queue) >= 1:
        del self.song_queue[0]
        source = os.path.join(self.QUEUE_PATH, self.song_queue[0])
        audio = MP3(source)
        await self.postEmbed(ctx, self.song_queue[0], audio.info.length)
        await self.voicechannel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
    else:
        await self.voicechannel.disconnect()
```

Note: async can be included in any def.
or you could do this

```
@commands.command() #If its on cog, if its not on cog change it to @client.command or @bot.command()
async def play_next(self, ctx):
    voicechannel = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if len(self.song_queue) >= 1:
        del self.song_queue[0]
        source = os.path.join(self.QUEUE_PATH, self.song_queue[0])
        audio = MP3(source)
        await self.postEmbed(ctx, self.song_queue[0], audio.info.length)
        await self.voicechannel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
    else:
        await self.voicechannel.disconnect()
```

or remove the `@commands.command()` and make another command like this

```
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
    await play_next(url)
    """Say something or add another code"""
```

Comment: The Problem here is that it tells me that play_next(ctx) has never been awaited

Comment: you're probably missing "await" on some of the code.

Comment: It still doesnt work...same error message. I edited my code for the current code

Comment: if its on `self.song_queue.append(song)` try `await self.song_queue.append(song)`

Comment: This is the Error message: C:\Users\4TL4S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py:611: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Musik_Player.play_next' was never awaited
  self.after(error)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: the song_queue is just a normal list, where i delete the first element

Comment: When i put a await infront of the queue.append this error message shows up: File "C:\Users\4TL4S\Documents\Coding\Discord_Development\src\cogs\music.py", line 38, in play
    await self.song_queue.append(song)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: i just thinked of something, what about you removed the `@commands.command` and let it be (Edited code above)

Comment: The Problem i have is that i dont quite understand how the finalizer "after" works. In principle i just want a "listener" which calls the Method "play_next" when the current song has ended. Maybe there is a better way doing this then with after

Comment: If you don't mind reading my [source code](https://www.github.com/RaphielHS/discord-py-bot/tree/master/cogs%2Fmusic.py) for some clue because im currently not on my laptop.